# Why is StrobeMediaPlayer.swf 253k in the "for Flash Player X" folder but 433k when compiled or in player/bin folder?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ant, osmf, strobe-media-playback

I have been trying to compile [StrobeMediaPlayback](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smp.adobe/files/) from source; I've managed to compile the project using ANT with the Flex 4.5.1 or Flex 6 SDK and also successfully compiled using Flash Builder 4.5 (as recommended by the project).

In all cases, compiling the SMP project results in a 433k StrobeMediaPlayback.swf. Also, StrobeMediaPlayback.swf located in `src/player/StrobeMediaPlayback/bin/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` ships as 433k.  My question then, is how on earth do I compile StrobeMediaPlayback.swf to 253k as it exists in the `for Flash Player 10.1` folder? It appears there is an external OSMF.swc file in this folder that is 233k - typically this gets bundled with the build... however, I can drop the 253k StrobeMediaPlayback.swf into a new project without the OSMF.swc file and it works fine.

So, if it turns out that I need to compile StrobeMediaPlayback without bundling the OSMF.swc, can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Relevant installation documentation that was impossible to find: http://osmf.org/dev/osmf/specpdfs/building-osmf.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, if it turns out that I need to compile StrobeMediaPlayback without bundling the OSMF.swc, can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Try,

- in your StrobeMediaPlayback project, mark the osmf.swc as an external library.
  (Project > Properties > Application Build Path > Library Path > OSMF > Link Type)